# Псевдографика, не получается выводить нормально

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть скрипт, который выводит слово в консольную команду. Со стороны выглядит как бегущая строка.

```
from os import system 
from time import sleep

from colorama import init, Fore, Style

init()
print(Fore.GREEN, Style.BRIGHT)

string = [

"|  |    |  ||_____   ||  ____  ||  ____  ||  |    |  |  |   __   ||__    __||  ___  ||__    __||  |  |  ||   _  \  |______  ||  |    |  |   /        \ |  ||  |    |  ||   \    /   | ",
"|  |____|  | _____|  || |____| || |____| |\  |____|  /  |  |__|_/    |  |   | |___| |   |  |   |  |__|  ||  | \  \  ______| |\  |____|  /  |    __    ||  |\  |____|  /|    \  /    | ",    
"|   ____   ||   __   ||  ______||  ______| \__    __/   |   __  \    |  |   |     __|   |  |   |   __   ||  |  |  ||   __   | \__    __/   |   |__|   ||  | \__    __/ |     \/     | ",        
"|  |    |  ||  |__|  || |       | |           |  |      |  |__|  | __|  |__ |  |\  \    |  |   |  |  |  ||  |_/  / |  |__|  |    |  |      |    __    ||  |    |  |    |   |\__/|   | ",        
"|__|    |__||________||_|       |_|           |__|      |________||________||__| \__\   |__|   |__|  |__||______/  |________|    |__|      |___|  |___||__|    |__|    |___|    |___| ",                   
]                                                  

def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]


while True:
    system('cls')
    print('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n')
    for j in range(5):
        string[j] = rotate(string[j], 0)
    print("\n".join(string))
    sleep(0.1)
```

Проблема в том, что не могу сделать эти слова выводит в двух строках. Вот, так надо выводить:
[image: Screenshot]

Помогите, пожалуйста. Подскажите, как надо. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: есть готовые библиотеки для таких буковок

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632995/how-to-easily-print-ascii-art-text

Comment: @eri есть, но я не могу выводить нормально, там слетает.

Answer (score 1):

Тут нет никаких двух строк. Есть несколько строковых переменных, которые образуют текст, если их расположить друг над другом в нужном порядке. Если нужно два слова, то создайте из каждой строки две с нужными символами и выводить в нужном порядке. У вас на изображении даже видно, как именно нужно сделать.